# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java

Sou novata em programação e o problema  pede para armazenar em vetor o nome de 10 produtos. Em seguida, o programa deve solicitar a faixa de produtos que deve
ser apresentada (por exemplo: de 3 a 7).

O erro diz:

"Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at aula2.Exercicio5.main(Exercicio5.java:21)"

```java
package aula2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercicio5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [] produto = new String[10];

        for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {

            Scanner p = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Insira o " + (i)+ "° produto de 10:");
            produto[i] = p.nextLine();
            p.close();
        }

        Scanner f = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Insira a faixa mínima:");
        int minimo = f.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Insira a faixa máxima:");
        int maximo = f.nextInt();

        for (int i=minimo; i<maximo+1; i++) {
            System.out.println(produto[i-1]);
        }
        f.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercicio5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [] produto = new String[10];

        Scanner p = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {


            System.out.println("Insira o " + (i+1)+ "° produto de 10:");
            produto[i] = p.nextLine();

        }

        System.out.println("Insira a faixa mínima:");
        int minimo = p.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Insira a faixa máxima:");
        int maximo = p.nextInt();

        for (int i=minimo-1; i<=maximo-1; i++) {
            System.out.println(produto[i]);
        }

        p.close();
    }
}
```

P.S. Aconselho a testar o input do utilizador para as variáveis minimo e maximo, para garantir que se encontram entre 0 e 10 e que mínimo <= máximo.

Comment: Pode dar mais detalhes? Em português?

Comment: O objecto Scanner é declarado e libertado fora do primeiro ciclo. A lógica para percorrer o array com o índice i não estava correta. Deves, apenas sugestão minha, testar os limites do máximo e mínimo inseridos pelo utilizador e até se min é menor que max.

Comment: Pode editar a resposta?

Comment: Maniero, sou nova nisso, estou tentando entender, já edito

Comment: Filipe, estamos no [pt.so] e todas as perguntas e respostas devem estar em português. Poderia [edit] sua resposta traduzindo-a e incluindo também a explicação do seu último comentário? Assim ela fica completa (futuros visitantes não precisarão "caçar" informações nos comentários) e também no idioma correto